# Jersey REST 2.0 Asynchronous request failed in the underlying container (Tomcat 7)

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I'm curious if anyone has been able to resolve this issue yet? I've done some searching but it still seems like it's an outstanding issue with Jersey 2 async REST implementation.
I have the following code:

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void asyncGet(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String result = veryExpensiveOperation();
                asyncResponse.resume(result);
            }
            private String veryExpensiveOperation() {
                return "got it too";
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

I'm using Servlet 3.0 so no web.xml ... Tomcat version is 7.0.54 and I have added the following line to server.xml

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

This was a Jersey Maven project so I have commented in the following

```
<artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
```

and commented out

```
<artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
```

I'm not sure what else I can do here, this is the stacktrace

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Attempt to suspend a connection of an asynchronous request failed in the underlying container.
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:391)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Attempt to suspend a connection of an asynchronous request failed in the underlying container.
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:312)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Any ideas???

Comment: I'm having the same issue but with Tomcat 8.5, Jersey REST & Firebase... None of the methods below work (or other suggestions on the internet for that matter)!!!

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you are using the latest version, as of the day of posting, use v2.13

In your  web.xml, make sure that the following is added to the servlet tag

```
<async-supported>true</async-supported>
```

Comment: "I'm using Servlet 3.0 so no web.xml" ... I mentioned it in my post :P

Comment: Oops sorry - web.xml is optional. Try setting the property in your ResourceConfig subclass. https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.0/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html#property%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Hi, can you give an example on how to set this property? I tried property("asyncSupported", true); it does not work

Comment: Netbeans 8.2 / Tomcat 8.0.27: I also had to disable HTTP monitor (Services -> Servers -> Right click on Apache Tomcat -> Properties -> uncheck Enable HTTP monitor). It looks like it is a [bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236064).

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to add Async support to **Filters** as well. I used a web.xml and could easily add async-support is true.

```
<filter>
        <description>Spring filter</description>
        <display-name>spring-filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>springFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
```

without a web.xml using @WebFilter it would be

```
@WebFilter(asyncSupported = true)
```

BTW: I am using jersey 2.4.1 and tomcat 7.0.41 (not the latest versions, I am aware of that)

Hopes this helps for you

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody faced with the same error in a test code in ([dropwizard.io](http://dropwizard.io)) framework while running test resource in `Junit` there is an option to use different test container factory(`Grizzly one's`) while initializing jersey client:

execution code:

```
ResourceExtension resources = ResourceExtension.builder()
            .setTestContainerFactory(new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory())
            .addResource(new FooResource())
            .build();

resources.getJerseyTest().target(path)
```

pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-grizzly-container.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I have been looking for

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit of an old question, but I was facing this issue exactly using Jersey2 (no web.xml configuration, only annotations) on Tomcat 8 - the sample resource for SSE broadcaster from the Jersey documentation threw the exact same exception.
I have noticed that I had a web.xml configuring the Guice and CORS filters, so, adding:

`<async-supported>true</async-supported>`

to each of these filters worked for me.